# How to disable soft keypad always for TextInputLayout EditText in Android?

Tags: android

Am using this fro hiding the keypad for EdtitText.

```
contributionMonth.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

This is working fine when I directly touch the EditText box. It doesn't work for some time. My case is when i put some input on another edittext meantime my keypad will be visible, in this meantime
if i entered text to that inputtype null edittext it accepts  the input. How to disable the input type as null for always?

Comment: Do i need to disable it's focus? Explain bit clear

Comment: Just disable it as follows `contributionMonth.setEnabled(false);`

Comment: it disabled the editText. I want my keypad only disabled for that particular editText. Because am using spinner on it